# In Excel, when using dynamic arrays, is there a way to use a function containing a range argument?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I'll use NETWORKDAYS() to illustrate.
Suppose I have three columns of data in Excel. Assume they occupy A1:C5 as follows:

- Column A: Start Date
- Column B: End Date
- Column C: Number of work days between the two

So, the cells in column C could be (ignoring the holiday argument for simplicity)

```
C1 = NETWORKDAYS(A1,B1)
C2 = NETWORKDAYS(A2,B2)
```

and so on, down to

```
C3 = NETWORKDAYS(A5,B5)
```

But of course I could *not* use the following array formula.

```
= {NETWORKDAYS(A1:A5,B2:B5)}
```

OK, that's unfortunate, but it's tolerable. Yes, I have to copy-paste the formula down across all the rows, but that wont kill me.

HOWEVER, the limitation becomes downright annoying with the advent of Dynamic Arrays. And that's because if columns A and B are both DAs, then I *could* use:

```
= NETWORKDAYS(A1#,B1#)
```

and that brings the huge benefit that I wouldn't have to know the length of those input arrays. Spilling would take care of that. Except, I can't get that benefit because Excel still pukes at ranges in the first two args for NETWORKDAYS().

And of course, NETWORKDAYS() is just one example. There are many similarly challenged functions++.

Is there a way around this?

---

++ Curiously, not all functions with scalar args suffer from this. An example is MATCH(), where the first argument is usually a scalar, but it can take a DA fine.

Answer (score 2):

We can force the issue with `IF({1},)`

```
=NETWORKDAYS(IF({1},A1#),IF({1},B1#))
```

[image]

Comment: What is this black magic sorcery?! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, DO remember the `IF({1},` thing, and do not forget the `{}`.

However, there is a second issue at hand which prevents the given answer from working if the data is built piece by piece, and it is a major deficiency in the `SPILL` functionality (or `Dynamic Arrays` if you prefer).

One cannot simply make a random reference as being a dynamic array:  using `A1#` does NOT lead to Excel looking at things and deciding you must mean every contiguously used cell below (Not to the right? Or both? Are we asking Excel to assume our direction?) and so treating such as an official array which can be referred to as "A1#".

You may define such a thing. Perhaps you enter `=A1:A110` in C1. A SPILL array will show in cells C1:C10 and using the `IF({1},` trick (and there are similar ones, but the `IF` is very, very simple and easy to apply) will get the SPILL output in whatever place you want it. Again though, not until YOU define a dynamic array will Excel bring the SPILL functionality into play.

Note, by the way, ONLY the one column needs to be defined as a dynamic array. You don't need to specify B1:B10 as one also. Either (or "one of however many" if more than two) parameter's range given as a separately defined dynamic array activates that functionality. Of course, you can do both and it works fine too.

So the answer is right, as far as it goes, that this is one of several similar things, and one of several different whole things, one can do to force a function built to take one cell as its parameters, period.

(This being one thing, another category of "thing" is to enclose the eventual formula, or formula part, in a function that DOES trigger SPILL functionality. Apparently, even for the functions of yore that famously always warned you that even if you give them a range, they will only use the "first" cell in the range (upper left) to produce A result, yes, even for them Excel always actually maintained the entire array offered with the range you gave, just didn't have a way, or no one realized and figured out how to make use of it (or even more alternatively, MS actually rewrote EVERY old function prepping for SPILL so they would hold the entire array, not cut it down internally to the single cell, then work... NO, they didn't rewrite a thing they didn't have to), to make use of it. Now we do though. I suspect several strategies for raising those old functions' bar will arise. But the answer is a simple, and an easy application (as in no obnoxious contortions to build it into the formula).

Another approach, from the old days, is to make the range a `Named Range` and offer the NR name. Many functions could then be coerced. And nowadays, since `LET()` in essence creates a Named Range (that overrides any more generally created one via the Named Range functionality matching an Excel 4 Macro capability (`SETNAME`)), you can use it, in conjunction with the coercing technique (`IF({1}` in this case). Look up coercing in general for lots more information you may find handy now and then. Neither of these actually forces the SPILL functionality to do anything evaluating the work, by the way, but since SPILL is always looking for arrays to display and they produce arrays internally for the result, Excel no longer cherrypicks that "first" value/cell for the output, but takes the whole array which SPILL dutifully displays fully or gives an error for.

(Yikes, there's a whole family of internet questions coming up there:  people wondering why their formulas give SPILL errors when the functions don't take more than a single cell input;  or the ranges they specify are only 20 cells but their formulas seem to be considering a whole row or column hence the SPILL errors, but how do they do that for ranges only 20 cells long? Well, yeah, I used `ROW(1:20)` instead of `SEQUENCE()` to properly limit what Excel was doing but... Another set of boring questions to come from all that. Anyway...)

But it does not work as shown unless the data columns the answer offers are already arrays which really can't happen if entering them one by one so... You have to define one of them as an array before you can really apply the idea to this question's issue.